# tinymce pre plugin button looks disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, pre

I am using tinymce in my rails 3.2 application.
I have added pre as a plugin in tinymce.yml in config. But the the button that appears on UI to add the code segment looks disabled. Why? There are no javascript or css errors on my page at all.